# Angular - Compress string for IndexedDB or LocalStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, compression

I need to find a way to compress big string value coming from webapi calls and store them into IndexedDB or LocalStorage...

I only need to store one single response that is about 5MB of size.

Question is:

Is there a way to compress string with typescript/angular using some kind of thirt part component?

And second question is: its better to use localstorage or IndexedDB for this kind of scenario?

Thanks to support

Comment: I am also looking for a solution. I liked LZstring in theory but importing it into Angular project turns for me into a nightmare;/

Comment: we are on the same ship bro...

Answer (score 1):

U cant trying to [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) to compress your strings.
Of course, indexedDB is the successor of localStorage but it has a browser support problem(indexedDB Support: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)). So If the support satisfies you then use indexedDB. The localStorage is more simple to use and has better support, but it's synchronous and has very limited storage(please take look to this [post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)).

for more about offline storages take a look to this [post](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa).

Comment: The point of this topic was string compression. I think where to store it is a solvable issue

Comment: As I have mentioned above you can use [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) library for string compression.